# flutter: Target of URI doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

When I try to open the flutter project of my developer, I get hundreds of errors, that he does not find multiple packages for instance. Packages that consist with the name of my app, so they are probably custom made. He says I should have everything and that it gives errors because my flutter version is newer than the one that the project recognises in vsc. Is this correct? And if so, how can I get these packages?

```
''''

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:fimber/fimber_base.dart'. 
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does      
exist.dart(uri_does_not_exist)
```

Comment: This happened to me after merging in the latest changes to `master` into my branch.
@xahid_rocks's solution below solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` , As far as I assume, related packages are not in the app, so you have to get them via pub get.

Comment: this did not work for me. Any alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to write where the Dart file is located in the import section, in a case of sth like this.

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:fimber/fimber_base.dart'.

Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does:

```
exist.dart(uri_does_not_exist)
```

Try to delete the import URI to this `fimber_base.dart` or, if you are using the Android Studio as your IDE, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, it should give the library to import.